# I am trying to read contents of doc/rtf file using FileHandler.readAsString, but it seems garbage values are getting displayed in output

Tags: java

***Code:***

```
try{
        String fileContent = FileHandler.readAsString(new File ("C:\\Src\\file1.doc"));
        System.out.println(fileContent);
   }
catch (IOException e)
   {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

*file1.doc contains: "Test Content Transfer"*

Comment: GIGO - what makes you think that a word doc / rtf only contains pure text?

Comment: If you want to read doc file use 3rd party library Apache POI

Comment: Thanks. I have just started learning Selenium Webdriver and dont know many things.